# .Net Web API Routing & Help Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am struggling to get the API help page to show all my API endpoints, and to show them in the style I want.

Here are my routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Orgs", "v1/Orgs/{orgId}", 
new { controller = "Orgs", orgId = RouteParameter.Optional });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("OrgDescendants", "v1/Orgs/{orgId}/Descendants", 
new { controller = "Orgs", action = "OrgDescendants" });
```

Here are all my controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Org> GetAllOrgs()

[HttpGet]
public Org Get(string orgId)

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("OrgDescendants")]
public List<Org> Descendants(string orgId)

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Org org)

[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(string orgId, Org org)

[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(string orgId)
```

And here are the endpoints that the help page displays:

```
GET v1/Orgs
POST v1/Orgs
PUT v1/Orgs/{orgId}
DELETE v1/Orgs/{orgId}
GET v1/Orgs/{orgId}/Descendants
```

As you can see, the help page is missing the following endpoint:

```
GET v1/Orgs/{orgId}
```

I have tried so many different routing permutations I have lost track. Whatever I try I always end up with some endpoints missing or 'incorrectly' formatted.

For example, I end up with:

```
GET v1/Orgs/{orgId}/Get
```

when I want:

```
GET v1/Orgs/{orgId}
```

or I end up with:

```
PUT v1/Orgs?orgId={orgId}
```

when I want:

```
PUT v1/Orgs/{orgId}
```

No matter what combination I try I can't seem to get them all the way I want them. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am guessing HelpPage thinks that the route `GET v1/Orgs/{orgId}` has conflicts between `Get(string orgId)` and `Descendants(string orgId)`. Actually you could probably try making a request to `GET v1/Orgs/{orgId}` and should see an error something like saying "Multiple actions were found..." etc.

Comment: When I define nested routes like this I usually set the nested resources as a different controller, it would be `DescendantsController` in your case. That way you can have a full rest API on the Descendants as well if needed. Maybe it's a workaround you can explore...

Comment: I had been thinking about moving descendants to their own controller but since they are orgs as well I had wanted to keep them in the same controller to save on duplicated code. It looks like that might be the best workaround for the time being though. I will give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy, this kind of problem is met, when there are problems with project architecture (hierarchy).

Moreover, you may try to add routers in a different way. For example:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(
            "UserProfiles",
            new Route("Profile/{uid}/{mode}", new ProfileRouterHandler("~/Profile/Default.aspx")));
```

The router handler would look something like:

```
public class ProfileRouterHandler: IRouteHandler
{
    private string VirtualPath { get; set; }
    public ProfileRouterHandler()
    {

    }

    public ProfileRouterHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string param = requestContext.RouteData.Values["uid"] as string;
        string mode = requestContext.RouteData.Values["mode"] as string;
        long id;
        long.TryParse(param, out id);
        if (id > 0)
        {
            string filePath = "~/Profile/Default.aspx?uid=" + param + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mode) ? "&mode=" + mode : "");
            VirtualPath = "~/Profile/Default.aspx";
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(filePath);
        }
        else
        {
            string filePath = "~/Profile/" + param + ".aspx";
            VirtualPath = filePath;
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(filePath);
        }

        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Page; 
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.